# IRC Bot not connecting to the channel

Tags: python, irc

I was following the tutorial on this site: http://wiki.shellium.org/w/Writing_an_IRC_bot_in_Python

When I opened the terminal in Ubuntu and ran screen python ircbot.py, below is the message I get.

```
:irc.codetalk.io NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:irc.codetalk.io NOTICE AUTH :*** Couldn't resolve your hostname; using your IP address   instead
PING :8F0ECB12
:irc.codetalk.io 451 JOIN :You have not registered
:8F0ECB12!nospoof@irc.codetalk.io PRIVMSG multhafa :VERSION
```

I don't know what to do after this. How do I connect it to a particular channel and actually see the nickname in the user list. This is my first brush with this kind of project.

Update: 2 minutes after I ran screen python ircbot.py in terminal, my laptop crashed. It happened twice. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: It seems you need to be registered to access to this IRC server.

Comment: Error 451 is `ERR_NOTREGISTERED`. As far as I can tell, that means the server thinks you aren't registering properly. Per [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812), to register, you should 1. send a `PASS` message if necessary; 2. send a `NICK` message; and 3. send a `USER` message. Make sure you're doing that correctly. (Actually, that tutorial looks pretty bad. You should be parsing the messages, not just using `find()` on them. Also, `send` might send only part of the message, and it's not handling that case. The list goes on.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice the

```
PING :8F0ECB12
```

line. To complete registration, you have to answer this correctly, with

```
PONG :8F0ECB12
```

This might be in violation to the RFC, but most clients don't have a problem with that (simply answer any `PING` message).

This required `PONG` response was added to prevent HTTP-POST requests on the IRC port.
Before, a special crafted POST request could be used to connect to an IRC server, join a channel and send some spam. The HTTP request will timeout after a while (the response is useless) but the damage has already be done. (Maybe you remember that dark times of freenode).

Comment: How do I do the PONG message?

Comment: How do you send `USER` etc?

Comment: Yes, I am a total newbie. So knowing the HOW code will really help?